# How can I record a memory address with lttng?

Tags: lttng

I have to migrate some code to LTTng. We were using syslog-like tool and using printf-like format...

I have found several log lines printing pointers with `%p` but I do not know how to "translate" those lines into LTTng.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using LTTng 2.7+, your best bet is using [`tracelog()`](https://lttng.org/docs/#doc-tracelog), a special API that was designed to ease the migration from logging to tracing.

You should be able to use `%p` with `tracelog()` since it uses the `vsprintf()` family of functions to format the recorded message.

If you already tread on the path to defining static tracepoints, I suggest using a CTF integer backed by a `uintptr_t` if your compiler supports C99, otherwise `unsigned long long` or perhaps `size_t` (which should be able to hold an address most of the time, although it's not guaranteed):

```
#include <stdint.h>

TRACEPOINT_EVENT(
    my_provider,
    my_memory_address,

    /* arguments (input) */
    TP_ARGS(
        const void *, address
    ),

    /* event fields (output)  */
    TP_FIELDS(
        ctf_integer_hex(uintptr_t, address, address)
    )
)
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
tracepoint(my_provider, my_memory_address, my_pointer);
```

Comment: Hi, sorry to add comment here, I just ask a question would you please check it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40698938/segmentation-fault-in-read-lttng-events-with-python